# How do I convert Python 2 code to python 3 code in GitBash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-bash

I have a file written in Python 2 and I want to convert the code to Python 3, while saving a file of both. How do you do this using Git Bash?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly: You want to convert code from python 2 to 3. That usually involves replacing code parts that are incompatible with the new version. Where do you see the connection to the git bash shell?

Comment: Have you tried using `2to3`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a copy of the file for Python3. I would copy the file and rename it with the Python version as part of the name and then rename the original file to also include the version. Something like:

```
cp foo.py foo36.py
mv foo.py foo27.py
```